# Paypal Sandbox = PimpAbort with return code 4002

Tags: exception, paypal, express-checkout

Im working on Paypal Expresscheckout (calling `SetExpressCheckout`) and as I fill the guest checkout form, I get this error on paypal page after its form is submitted. Any idea? It was working till yesterday.

```
PimpAbort with return code 4002
File: applogic/web/FinancialInstrument/CreditCard/implementation/CreditCardALIImpl.cpp
Func: handleCreditCardError Line: 4445

Backtrace: Utility::WebPimpExceptionHandlerALIImpl::handle_PimpAbortException(PimpAbortException const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&) Utility::WebPimpExceptionHandlerALIImpl::handle_exceptions(PPException const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&) MerchantPaymentWeb::exception_handler(PimpWebAppContext const&, PPException const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&) Riprap::dispatch_loop(Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::DispatchAction&, Riprap::WebAppReturn&, String const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::dispatch_wrapper(OutputStream&, Riprap::EPRegistry const&, Riprap::WebAppContext const&, Riprap::WebAppReturn const&, String const&, bool const&, Riprap::DispatchInterceptorRegistry const&) Riprap::entry_point(HTTPInterface&, Riprap::CGIVars&, OutputStream&, String const&, String const&) main

Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3174), Use of pimp_rc (7184), Use of pimp_rc (3197), Use of pimp_rc (14816), Use of pimp_rc (9449), Use of pimp_rc (9445), Use of pimp_rc (4814), Use of pimp_rc (3507), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (3778), Use of pimp_rc (4007), Use of pimp_rc (4020), Use of pimp_rc (7003), Use of pimp_rc (3583), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3021), Use of pimp_rc (3242), Use of pimp_rc (3165), Use of pimp_rc (3101), Use of pimp_rc (3085), Use of pimp_rc (3209), Use of pimp_rc (3174), Use of pimp_rc (3043), Use of pimp_rc (3241), Use of pimp_rc (3082), Use of pimp_rc (3129), Use of pimp_rc (3567), Use of pimp_rc (3235), Use of pimp_rc (3236), Use of pimp_rc (3508), Use of pimp_rc (3507), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (3124), Use of pimp_rc (3047), Use of pimp_rc (3224), Use of pimp_rc (3093), Use of pimp_rc (3253), Use of pimp_rc (3254), Use of pimp_rc (3083), Use of pimp_rc (3137), Use of pimp_rc (3256), Use of pimp_rc (14268), Use of pimp_rc (14267), Use of pimp_rc (14266), Use of pimp_rc (14269), Use of pimp_rc (14264), Use of pimp_rc (14265), Use of pimp_rc (14244), Use of pimp_rc (3084), Use of pimp_rc (3254), Use of pimp_rc (3083), Use of pimp_rc (3137), Use of pimp_rc (3070), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3198), Use of pimp_rc (3011), Use of pimp_rc (10021), Use of pimp_rc (3199), Use of pimp_rc (3015), Use of pimp_rc (3014), Use of pimp_rc (3200), Use of pimp_rc (3257), Use of pimp_rc (3012), Use of pimp_rc (3141), Use of pimp_rc (3535), Use of pimp_rc (3504), Use of pimp_rc (10022), Use of pimp_rc (6702), Use of pimp_rc (3001), Use of pimp_rc (3120), Use of pimp_rc (3517), Use of pimp_rc (3531), Use of pimp_rc (3201), Use of pimp_rc (3803), Use of pimp_rc (6834), Use of pimp_rc (3807), Use of pimp_rc (3808), Use of pimp_rc (3810), Use of pimp_rc (3812), Use of pimp_rc (3809), Use of pimp_rc (3805), Use of pimp_rc (2002), Use of pimp_rc (3177), Use of pimp_rc (3051), Use of pimp_rc (3510), Use of pimp_rc (4003), Use of pimp_rc (3013), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (3300), Use of pimp_rc (3286), Use of pimp_rc (6681), Use of pimp_rc (14605), Use of pimp_rc (10361), Use of pimp_rc (14353), Use of pimp_rc (14817), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (2001), Use of pimp_rc (4001), Use of pimp_rc (11045), Use of pimp_rc (3593), Use of pimp_rc (4071), Use of pimp_rc (3514), Use of pimp_rc (4022), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (4011), Use of pimp_rc (6031), Use of pimp_rc (14029), Use of pimp_rc (4002), Use of pimp_rc (1020), Use of pimp_rc (1019), Use of pimp_rc (1026)
```

Comment: Were you ever able to find a resolution to this, other than to wait and try again later? I'm hitting this right now in Sandbox. Also tried a Chrome incognito window to ensure no cookies were interfering.

Answer (score -2):

Pimp code 4002 has to do with a transaction being declined by PayPal's risk model. So basically PayPal's risk model blocked the transaction as too risky of a transaction. I would suggest testing in sandbox mode if you are testing.